# Comparing and extracting similar strings from 2 arrays in java, double worded strings not compared, .split(",") returns blank

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I know that similar question was asked before and I asked this yesterday, however I still cannot find the answer to my problem!

I am comparing arrays and extracting similarities with the HashSet.

```
final String[] abc = nlp_text.split(",");
final String[] xyz = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.xyz);

final HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
for(String a : abc) set.add(a.toLowerCase());
final HashSet<String> set1 = new HashSet<>();
for(String a : xyz) set1.add(a.toLowerCase());
set.retainAll(set1);
String[] pqr= {};
pqr = set.toArray(pqr);
```

This returns blank! Although there are similar strings separated by comma! nlp_text is the array list of names, ex: "Nataly Portman, Johnny Depp, John Doe, Jane Doe, Natasha, Sasha, ... etc". Array xyz also names (database of names, so around 300).

If split by (" ") works on single word strings, however does not work on double word strings. For instance, strings "John" and "Doe" will be recognised separately, but "John Doe" will not. Thus, tried with comma, "-", ".", even double space! Nothing!

any idea why? thanks in advance!!!

Comment: There's no context here--we can't see your data.

Comment: i edited my question. hope is more understandable...

Comment: Please include an [mre]. This means we should be able to copy and paste your code into our ide and run/debug your code. Include the arrays with data. String s = "John Doe, Sally Schmoe". That sort of thing. Please make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: oh, thanks for the comment! will def do next time i have question! but, @mlc below helped me, and it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption would be that you have spaces.
Your nlp_text probably looks like that:

`"Nataly Portman, Johnny Depp, John Doe, Jane Doe, Natasha, Sasha"`

and you array is something like that:

`{ "Johnny Depp", "John Doe", "Jane Doe", "Natasha" }`

If yes, after split you will have spaces in some elements of `final String[] abc`.

If that's the case, add `trim()` after `toLowerCase()`:

`a.toLowerCase().trim()`